# Outlets not working

Tags: receptacle

House was rewired by friends a couple years ago. All the outlets in my house were switched out but 2 in my laundry room. That's the room with the breaker box and I had all my stuff for the house stored in there. I think that's the reason why they didn't get switched out. Anyway. my laundry room shares a wall with the kitchen. My stove is on that wall. The power doesn't work on either side of the wall. I've had to use an extension cord to use my stove and switch it to use my washer. Every other outlet works in my house. Is it possible that the whole wall doesn't work b/c the old outlet is still installed? There's only 1 outlet on each side. The one for my stove was replaced but it doesn't work either. I'm at a loss and really hope this is the issue.

Comment: It's likely your friends did not hook the old outlets to the new service panel (breaker box).

Comment: Is that possibly something I could correct myself or should I  have an electrician do it? The friends have moved away and nowhere close to come over and correct it themselves.

Comment: Is this a gas or an electric stove, BTW?

Comment: It is a gas stove.

Comment: It takes knowledge and experience to do electrical work. Call an electrician you think you can trust.

Answer (score 1):

By code a washer receptacle should be on its own 20A circuit. It sounds like someone at sometime went back to back and tapped the washer circuit to install a receptacle to serve the 120V controls for the oven. Since controls usually use very little power I see no problem with that.

What you need to do is find the washer circuit in you panel and see if there is a breaker problem or for some reason. The panel should be labeled and should tell you which breaker is the washer circuit. What are the odds on that? Regardless, you might open the receptacles and check to see if a wire has pulled loose. **MAKE SURE ALL POSSIBLE CIRCUITS ARE DEAD.** If it's not that then the problem is in the panel.

I always hesitate to tell someone who isn't licensed to open a panel and check the breakers and circuitry because bad things can happen and you need to be properly trained. If it isn't a tripped 20A breaker it might be wise to have a professional help you from there.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  My house was built in 1864. I believe my laundry room and kitchen were the last add-ons to the house in the 60's. The people that lived here before liked to jerry rig everything.  The guys that rewired my house said I was very lucky the house didn't burn down. Several wires in attic were melted bc of the way they were wired. As well as some wires not going where they said they were. If it requires getting into the breaker box, I will call an electrician!  I'll check out the other things first and keep you posted.  Thanks again!

Comment: Here is the problem with that: 210.11(C)(2) Laundry Branch Circuits. In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least one additional 20-ampere branch circuit shall be pro-vided to supply the laundry receptacle outlet(s) required by 210.52(F). **This circuit shall have no other outlets.**

Comment: I think I would agree with RME , code also states no other loads on the countertop circuits but allows clocks and electronics for a gas stove , this is a case I bet the AHJ would allow. Back when the home was built would be the code standard , new outlets dosent require total updating to modern code.

Answer (score 0):

If I had 50 reputation I'd just comment :)

But I had a similar issue a few days ago, all wires were intact, GFCI receptacles worked fine, and it was only a room and a half that was out of power, no breakers flipped. It came down to one of the receptacles had a wire that was bent and about to break; your problem sounds like a similar issue

When I changed the other 4 receptacles the wires in the back were loose from being so old...that rung the dangerous bell :/

I'm no electrician but I'm pretty sure the washer and dryer should both have their own breaker apart from the kitchen.

Comment: Washers have only recently been required to have there own circuit when the home was rewired in the 60' s there was no code requirement for a dedicated or gfci.